# Finding PKCS version while having the SSL certificate and the public and private keys

Tags: cryptography, pki

I'm new to PKI and need to know something. I'm not even sure if my question makes sense so excuse me in advance. If we have the SSL certificate and the public and private keys, can we find which version of PKCS is used ? Like PKCS#1 RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5 or another ?
Thank you!

Comment: As the answer hints at but politely declines to state explicitly, it doesn't make sense. There are many different PKCS standards at play when using an SSL certificate, so much more specificity is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should have some text/base64 encoded PEM files. In those files you can see the type by the `----BEGIN` line in the private key file.

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` means you have an RSA private key in PKCS#1 format.

`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` means you have an RSA private key in PKCS#8 format.

For all the formats see https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Actually this is the kind of information I found. And in this case, with the data I have, can I determine the padding that is being used?

Comment: @Foued Padding is only used in case the key is encrypted so you have key an PKCS#8 with the text `BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY`?

Comment: in this case, the padding will be the difference of characters between the file having -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and the one having BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ?